# GitHub Test Instances - CLI access

Tags: testing, github

On the [Magento GitHub Repository](https://github.com/magento/magento2) it is possible to spin up instances for verifiying bugs / testing pull requests.

This is done by pinging the magento bot

```
@magento give me test instance
```

Is is possible to also access the CLI of such a test instance to conduct more diffcult tests / steps which involve the CLI?

I did not find a hint in [the documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/contributor-guide/contributing.html#vanilla-pr).

EDIT: I tried to install https://github.com/magefan/module-cli like this [in a GitHub issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35158):

```
@magento give me 2.4-develop instance with extensions magefan/module-cli
```

But I do not have the "System -> Tools -> Command Line" menu